# Count number of SQL tables in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database with many tables. I was wondering how I can use PHP to count the total number of tables in the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'dbName';
```

OR

```
USE databasename; SHOW TABLES; SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Answer (score 2):

Do query to `information_schema.tables`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='database_name';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with an sql statement:

```
select count(*) from information_schema.tables
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'dbName';

Answer (score 0):

Use the below Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='database_name';
```